# Can't see tasks in aptana

Tags: aptana, task, todo

I wonder why I can't see my `// TODO:` descriptions in my Task View in Aptana.
When I rightclick at the line number and choose <kbd>Add Task</kbd> it works and I can see my task in the
**Window > Show View > Tasks**

But when I just write a comment like this `//TODO: fix this line as soon as possible`. 
Then it doesn't show up in the Task list.

When I check my preferences **Window > Preferences > Aptana Studio > Tasks**, there's `TODO`, `XXX` and `FIXME` in that list, so it looks like it should work, but it doesn't.

The code I'm working at is an Aptana Project Aswell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem were that I had to change the type of the project in aptana.

The project was a Web project first, and WEB projects doesn't support TODO's in default.
Change the project to a PHP project and it works.

Maybe you can fix this somehow to make Web projects support todo's but I fixed it by changing the project type.

Comment: It worked for me. I think there's no reason it is implemented for PHP projects but not for Web projects

Comment: I agree totally, there's really no logic for that but it seems like that's the case. Does this problem still exist? I don't use Aptana right now.

Answer (score 0):

My current project is web based and you can create comments like

```
/**
 * TODO do some stuff here
 */
```

Aptana will recognize "TODO" keyword and will put colored rectangle(color is dependent on the editing theme set in preferences) on the right side of the screen next to the scrollbar.

To create task, right click on the line numbers vertical bar and context menu will appear. Click the Add task menu item. Once you do this it will appear in the tasks panel window.

Plus you can mark the task as completed or set priority, high, normal and low.

[image: Aptana TODO tasks]

Answer (score -1):

If you want to define your own task type, you must first add it in preferences **Window > Preferences > Aptana Studio > Tasks**, then you can add a new configuration on **Configure content** in task view.